# ArangoDB, Java, how to deserialize a polymorphic list

Tags: java, json, arangodb

I'm using ArangoDB 3.1, with the Java Driver 4.1.10.

This version is using Velocypack.

I'm trying to deserialize / unmarshall a list of an object (`Item`) where there are various subclasses (eg `SimpleItem`, `ComplexItem`) that might be in that list.  ie it's a polymorphic list.

Serialising is fine, the full object is correctly persisted, with all attributes, for all Item based classes.

Deserialising is not so great, only the attributes that are declared in `Item` are populated in the new Java Object.

I know that for jackson and gson, there are methods available for managing deserialisation/unmarshalling polymorphic lists from json.  eg, adding a `_class` attribute with the fully qualified java class in the json.

My question is, how can this be done with velocypack?

thanks,
Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible but I've created an [github issue](https://github.com/arangodb/java-velocypack/issues/1) for that.

Comment: OK - Thanks for doing that.